# PHP scp file from remote server

Tags: php, scp, setuid, suphp

How do I from a PHP script scp a file from a remote server ?

I have tried `shell_exec("scp remote:file dir")` but that does not work because user `apaache` does not have a shell associated on the remote server, and can therefore not do ssh.

I have tried to create a `Copy.sh` setuid script created as `user1` and use `shell_exec("Copy.sh file dir")`. However the Apache server (or PHP?) is not changing the uid when `Copy.sh` is executing despite the setuid flag.

This article
https://serverfault.com/questions/7589/how-do-you-run-a-php-script-as-the-files-owner-rather-than-as-the-webserver-us
advices to install `suPHP`, which I seem not have installed. Is that the way to go ? I have `mod_suexec` installed, but this module seems only to be able to change uid of the PHP script itself. Can it be (ab)used to do what I want ?

Perhaps there is a way to supply the ssh keys of `user1` to the PHP script, so it can do the copy ?

Comment: You can specify the remote user to connect, only if not specified it uses your current user: `scp someusername@remote:file dir`

Comment: Did try that, but did not debug further because I would think user `apache` can not just use the keys of user `someusername`.

Comment: Yeah, but you could just add the PubKey of Apache user to the `authorized_keys` file of `someusername` on remote.

Comment: Ahh, I am so stupid. With your help got it working. However for reasons I don't understand I could not do `scp user1@remote:file dir` but had to do `ssh user1@remote scp file local:dir`

Comment: Weird. I think it should also work without `ssh`. But if it's working for you it's fine either way.

Comment: Thinking about it there is a difference between the 2 commands: First will try to write the file as Apache user to your local dir, second will write it as `user1` as you don't specify `apache` in the `scp` from `remote`. So if Apache has no write-permissions on `dir` (only `user1` has), it would explain that the first doesn't work.

Comment: Explanation more simple. For the `ssh` command I also used the option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to get it working. Adding this to `scp` it also works.

Comment: I tried to compile everything relevant in an answer, if you want to check that / close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify in `scp` which remote-user should be used to connect:

```
scp someusername@remote:file dir
```

If you want to run this as Apache-user, you will need to add the PubKey of Apache to the `authorized_keys` file of `someusername` on remote.

---

If Apache-user never connected to remote via SSH before, it may not trust the HostKey. You should add it to the `known_hosts` file of the user, for example by interactively (in a shell) connecting to remote as Apache-user and typing `yes` when asked. Or disable the checks using `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, however this has security implications.